# Taming XCode's auto-complete options

Tags: objective-c, xcode, autocomplete

I am fairly new to XCode and the Objective-C language.

When I am instantiating a class, for example an NSMutableArray, XCode will provide a whole lot of auto-complete options. Even for an empty class which simply extends an NSObject has many options, most of which seem completely useless.

What is the reason for having so many auto-complete options, or can they be "tamed" in the preferences?

NOTE: This is unintentionally a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591730/taming-xcodes-auto-complete-options).

Comment: Oops, this was meant to be on Stack Overflow. Can someone migrate it please?

Comment: I'm very interested in the general question "how much can you modify the auto-complete behaviour of XCode".   I imagine lots of people would like to know that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some interesting information, here:

http://macdevelopertips.com/xcode/xcode-code-completion.html

You might also consider making [custom macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5013332/how-to-create-custom-text-macros-in-xcode).