# create custom code completion macro in xcode 6.1

Tags: xcode6, xcode6.1

How do i create a custom code completion macro in xcode 6.1

answer to [How to create custom "Text Macros" in Xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5013332/how-to-create-custom-text-macros-in-xcode) does not seems to work as "Contents/PlugIns/TextMacros.xctxtmacro/Contents/Resources" does not exist anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I have just been searching for this too, and I found the solution.

- Select the snippet that you want to make the macro with.
- Drag the selected text to the Snippets Draw.
- Inside the edit box, add the 'short-cut' that you want to use in the "Completion Shortcut" edit field.
- Set the required "Completion Scopes", if required.
  [image: XCode 6 - Text Macro Image]
  Viola.